# how to clear iOS remote notification

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

After push a message to APN sever, every time I open the app, `didReceiveRemoteNotification`  will call and receive the push data, how can i get rid of them?

but `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey` is null

After I did some searching, I added these two lines in the code but it's still not working

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

Answer (score 1):

If your badge count is already 0, setting it to 0 won't have any effect. Try setting the badge count to a meaningless number first, and then setting it to 0.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];    
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 99];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
```